# Web Deploy Package Error 'File ... does not exist'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012, web-deployment-project

I've trying to package up and old MVC 3 project to send it out but I keep getting a strange error where it telling me

'The file '/Views/Shared/print.Master' does not exist.  /Views/Questionnaire/View.aspx'

But I can clearly see the file and have renamed it to try and fix it but no luck, then I tried changing the package settings to include everything but that too didn't fix it so does anybody have any idea why this could be happening? (btw it's a 2nd master file)

Any ideas or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the file there in your windows file explorer?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Yes, as far as I can see there should be no reason why it says it can't exist as every where it should be it is so I half wondered if making the package it would only accept a single master file or if there was someone other issue which could cause this.

Comment: Found the issue, it's build action was set to 'none' for some reason so changed it to 'Content' and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Glad you managed to fix it. Could you post it as an answer so others with the same problem in the future have something to go on.

Comment: I'd thought I couldn't submit an answer within 2 days but instead it was that I couldn't accept it for another 2 days.

Comment: You cannot accept your own answer within the first 2 days after posting it. You can accept other people's answers. But answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged. After all, SO is not just there for the asker, but also for those that encounter similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to check file Properties and set 'Build Action' to 'Content'.